# Show Specific Tab in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following lack of knowledge on javascript. I have a nav-tab menu with 5 different tabs that can be expanded. But I want when the page loads a spesific tab (based on the previous page or arguments in the url) to be expanded. On the bootstrap page they have the example: 
`<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#myTab a:last').tab('show');
  })
</script>` 
My question is that I have no idea what 'a' is and I can't get it to pass an argument so that for instance my second tab to be shown. If I pass integer or #reference instead of 'last' it does not work. Anyone knows what is the right syntax here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#myTab a:last` is a jQuery selector that means *"the last `<a>` tag contained in the element with id `#myTab`"*. So that function runs the `show` method on the element that matches that selector.

If you want to select a different element, you can use any jQuery selector. There are lots of them: CSS standard selectors plus [these ones](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

For your specific issue, you can select the second tab by passing its `#id` or by using `:nth-child(2)` (wich means *"the elements that are a second child"*).

Comment: Must say that if you post your markup maybe we can find a more accurate solution